# add subviews generated by autoayout to a parent view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout

This is my very first program in autolayout.

**Basic problem:** i am not able to add subviews(a uibutton and a uilabel) to a superview(a containerview).Subviews are just out of bond of superview or say not clipped.

[image: out put from my code]

I have added commented in detail to be better understanding of code.

**What i want:**
i dont care whereever containerview is but i want both subviews to be add in containerview with 0 padding from all sides.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

**//create a uibutton with dynamic text(MAX_WIDTH=500, height = 60) and uilabel of fixed size(60, 60).Done
//create pin of fixed 2 pixes between UIButton and UILabel.Done
//put above created views in container view, it will max to 562 width and fix 60 height, so UIButton and UIlabel should fill container view with no top, bottom, left and right.Fail**

//this will be containing my button and my label
UIView *superview = self.view;

UIView *containerView = [UIView new];
[containerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[containerView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [superview addSubview:containerView];
//this will be containing my button and my label

UILabel *mylabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
[mylabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[mylabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
mylabel.text = @"MyLabel";

UIButton *mybutton = [UIButton
                      buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[mybutton setTitle:@"My Button ye ye yey yeyeyye yeyey"
          forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[mybutton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[mybutton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

[containerView addSubview:mylabel];
[containerView addSubview:mybutton];


NSDictionary * views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(mybutton,mylabel);
//create pin of fixed 2 pixes between UIButton and UILabel.Done
NSArray * horizontalConstraintsforbuttons = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[mybutton(<=500)]-2-[mylabel(60)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
NSArray * heightConstraintforbutton = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[mybutton(==60)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
NSArray * heightConstraintforLabel = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[mylabel(==60)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];

[containerView addConstraints:horizontalConstraintsforbuttons];
[containerView addConstraints:heightConstraintforbutton];
[containerView addConstraints:heightConstraintforLabel];


//container view specific constraints//**it must be ideally <=562, but then this container view disappears, please hep to fix** 
NSArray *widthConstraintForConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[containerView(==560)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(containerView)];

NSArray *heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[containerView(==60)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(containerView)];

[superview addConstraints:widthConstraintForConstraint];
[superview addConstraints:heightConstraint];


[superview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0]];

[superview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0]];
```

}

Any suggestion? :)

Comment: Can you try to [[**** alloc] init] every object? I saw that you did it to UILabel but boy for the rest. Any reason why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VFL for each of your subviews is missing a relationship with the parent view. Autolayout is assuming your constraints should be in relation to the top-level view — what you've defined as `self.view`.

Here's where your problem is.

```
NSDictionary * views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(mybutton,mylabel);
//create pin of fixed 2 pixes between UIButton and UILabel.Done
NSArray * horizontalConstraintsforbuttons = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[mybutton(<=500)]-2-[mylabel(60)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
NSArray * heightConstraintforbutton = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[mybutton(==60)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
NSArray * heightConstraintforLabel = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat
```

First, add your containerView to that dictionary so you can refer to it in VFL:

```
NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(mybutton,
                                                         mylabel,
                                                         containerView);
```

Then in your VFL, use the pipe operator (`|`) to tell autolayout to place your subviews in relation to their immediate parent.

```
NSArray * horizontalConstraintsforbuttons = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[mybutton(<=500)]-2-[mylabel(60)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
NSArray * heightConstraintforbutton = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[mybutton(==60)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
NSArray * heightConstraintforLabel = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[mylabel(==60)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
```

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do with the horizontal placement of those views, but this should get you back on track. I recommend reading [this post on VFL](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/01/31/visual-format-language-for-autolayout/), too.

---

### Edit

I sort of see what you're trying to do now. First, base your values at *1x* when working with VFL and autolayout. As an example, a width of 560 is larger than the largest possible iPhone screen:

```
NSArray *widthConstraintForConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[containerView(==560)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(containerView)];
```

Let's pretend you just wanted `containerView` to match the width of the device. That would look like this:

```
@"H:|[containerView]|"
```

Those pipe operators outside the containerView are saying that you want the leading (left side) and trailing (right side) space of `containerView` to be flush with the superview.

Alternatively, let's say you wanted your view to be slightly smaller than the width of the device (`560/2`).

```
@"H:[containerView(==280)]"
```

You're already horizontally centering `containerView` elsewhere, so it'll appear in the center of it's superview.

Let's then assume you want your red label to (actually) have a width of 60 and your green button to have a width less than or equal to 250 (`500/2`). That would look like this:

```
@"H:|[mybutton(<=250)]-2-[mylabel(==60)]|"
```

Since these are subviews of `containerView` (and we told that to autolayout earlier), the pipe operators are saying you want

1. the leading space (left side) of `mybutton` to be flush with `containerView`.
2. the trailing space (right side) of `mylabel` to be flush with `containerView`.

Since `mylabel` has a width of 60, `mybutton` will be narrower (thanks to `<=`) to satisfy constraints, depending on the width of `containerView`.

Comment: thank you very much. the main problem was with view dictionary.
Now i removed width constant for container view, so it will grow when it's subview will grow.So no more need of hardcoded 280 or 560

Comment: a quick question i can open new thread if it deserves, can same thing be acheived by UIHorizontalStackView. I will try but is it the situation where stackview can be used?